# how do i get my site web icon from direct link

Tags: html, css, icons, favicon

I would like to have my site’s logo shown in the icon area of the title rather than the default white document.
i use :

```
<head>   <LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/~image/favicon.ico"> </head>
```

but nothing showing

browser used is : Baidu Browser .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need attribute **`rel="icon"`**. Can set multiple with diff sizes:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16"/>
```

Comment: thank u bro it's work